# Draw corner round at layoutSubviews ,but not work for all screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to add top left and top right corner round at first cell
and bottom left,right corner round at last cell

I set param corners for cell

[image]

and draw corner round use UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer at layoutSubviews

It works fine at iphone6 screen size

[image]

But i did not work at other Screen Size
seem cell did not update it's width at 6plus size

[image: iphone6 plus size]

here iphone5 screen size miss top left and bottom left corner

**Please help me , tried many way didn't find why**

[image: iphone5 size]

Comment: try to call it inside `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`

Comment: @JuicyFruit perfect~~!!!, thank you so much!

Comment: added as answer. glad I could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've faced similar problem and applying mask inside

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //draw
}
```

block helped.